# What Statistical Test to Use with Two Categories of Quanitative Data Based on an Independent Variable

Tags: anova, t-test

I have data that is comparing pay rates for males and females (y-axis) based on how long they've been employed in a department (in months, x-axis). Essentially, there's two points, one female pay rate point and one male pay rate point for each color-coded department and they are based on longevity (so a female point may be employed 30 months at 23 dollars an hr and a male point might be employed 32 months at 25 dollars an hr in the same department).

I know the data is non-parametric as it's not normally distributed.

However, I am stuck on what kind of test to use to analyze the data on the graph that I have. At first I thought it was a t-test, but then I started leaning towards a two-way ANOVA and now I'm just completely lost.

Comment: Is your data a random sample?

Comment: Is each point an average for each sex for each department?